# Inconsistent Download 'Failed - Path too long' Error using Python Selenium Chromedriver

Tags: python, ajax, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Stack: `Windows 8.1, Python 3.4.3.4, Selenium 2.46, Chromedriver 2.16`

I'm using Selenium Python bindings with Chromedriver to automate some downloads from the following URL: `r'http://financials.morningstar.com/'`

I have set up the following chromedriver preferences:

```
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {'download.default_directory':symbol_dir}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
chromeOptions.add_extension(self.chromeUBlock_path)  
chromedriver_path = self.chromedriver_path
```

Furthermore I have set up the following selenium code to run the download which works without a problem and downloads to the correct file location etc.:

```
symbol = 'AAPL' # test symbol
IS_anl_statement = 'income-statement'
IS_anl_abbrev    = 'is'
url_anl = self.mstar_base_url + r'{}/{}.html?t={}&region=usa&culture=en-US'
IS_anl  = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path, chrome_options=chromeOptions)
IS_anl.set_page_load_timeout(90)

    try:        
        IS_anl.get(url_anl.format(IS_anl_statement, IS_anl_abbrev, symbol))
        anl_element = WebDriverWait(IS_anl, 90).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.LINK_TEXT, 'Annual')))
        anl_csv_element = WebDriverWait(IS_anl, 90).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.CSS_SELECTOR,self.css_path_export)))
        anl_csv_element.click()
        for i in range(1,10,1):
            time.sleep(i/50)
            if os.path.isfile(anl_file_string)==True:
                break    
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    IS_anl.quit()
```

However, when running the download with the following abbreviation (simply substituting `balance-sheet` in for `income-statement` like so:

```
    BS_anl_statement = 'balance-sheet'
    BS_anl_abbrev    = 'bs'
```

and the remaining Selenium code exactly the same I get the dreaded download error:
`Failed-Path Too Long`

This is strange because the actual filepath is Not Too Long. I in fact tested the download in 3 different directory's each with a shorter filepath than the last. The final example path is: `r"C:\mstar_data\\"`

I'm stuck. The only difference I can see between the two download attempts is the actual `CSV` link. But even in this case the `Income-Statement` download url is in fact longer than the `Balance-Sheet` so again I'm stuck. Here they are:

I/S CSV url: 
`http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/ReportProcess4CSV.html?&t=XNAS:ZUMZ&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=&reportType=is&period=12&dataType=A&order=asc&columnYear=5&curYearPart=1st5year&rounding=3&view=raw&r=573205&denominatorView=raw&number=3`

B/S CSV url:
`http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/ReportProcess4CSV.html?&t=XNYS:A&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=&reportType=bs&period=12&dataType=A&order=asc&columnYear=5&curYearPart=1st5year&rounding=3&view=raw&r=558981&denominatorView=raw&number=3`

Any help on this inconsistency would be a great help and definitely appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I can't tell what is the problem at the moment but I would clean the URL with Bitly.

Comment: There is an open [bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=137925) for Chrome that is quite similar. If the file Chrome is trying to write becomes read-only, this incorrect error is thrown. Is there anything that might try to use the downloaded file too soon, before it would finish downloading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a workaround for this issue. @Skandigraun was right there was a piece of code that was trying to use the downloaded file too soon.

I used `Advanced Uninstaller` to clear all temporary files, internet history and so on. 
I restarted my computer.
I altered the following code block regarding Skandigraun comments from:

```
for in range(1, 10, 1):
    time.sleep(i/50)
    if os.path.isfile(anl_file_string)==True:
            break
```

to:

```
for i in range(1, 10, 1):
    time.sleep(i/20) # changed from 50 to 20
    if os.path.isfile(anl_file_string)==True:
            break
```

and I added:

```
finally:
    IS_anl.quit()
```

Now the code runs with much more stability. I believe the os call to test if the file existed was happening too quickly/frequently and it caused a download failure. I added the `finally` statement to the `try/except` loop to close the browser no matter what happened. This prevented the script from hanging if there was a problem accessing the site, timeout errors etc.